# How to implode multi tree array to string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

I am trying implode this type of array to string. How can I do this ?

```
Array ( 
  [58] => Array ( 
    [272] => Array ( ) 
    [273] => Array ( ) 
    [274] => Array ( ) 
    [275] => Array ( ) 
    [276] => Array ( ) 
    [507] => Array ( ) 
  )
  [182] => Array ( 
    [46] => Array ( ) 
    [96] => Array ( ) 
  ) 
  [271] => Array ( 
    [2] => Array ( ) 
    [75] => Array ( ) 
    [80] => Array ( ) 
  ) 
  [277] => Array ( ) 
  [278] => Array ( 
    [4] => Array ( [174] => Array ( ) ) 
    [14] => Array ( ) 
    [36] => Array ( ) 
    [57] => Array ( ) 
    [279] => Array ( ) 
    [280] => Array ( ) 
    [281] => Array ( ) 
  ) 
)
```

I want to get result like: 58, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 507, 182 ...

Comment: It would help if you could present that example properly formatted, instead of just one long line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say your array is pretty strange but here is what i got from your code and request :

```
$thing = Array ( 
        58 => Array ( 272 => Array ( ), 273 => Array ( ), 274 => Array ( ), 275 => Array ( ), 276 => Array ( ), 507 => Array ( ) ),
        182 => Array ( 46 => Array ( ), 96 => Array ( ) ),
        271 => Array ( 2 => Array ( ), 75 => Array ( ), 80 => Array ( ) ),
        277 => Array ( ),
        278 => Array ( 4 => Array ( 174 => Array ( ) ), 14 => Array ( ), 36 => Array ( ), 57 => Array ( ), 279 => Array ( ), 280 => Array ( ), 281 => Array ( ) ) 
      );
$temp=[];
function husk_that_thing($array,&$temp)
{
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
  {
    $temp[]=$key;
    if($value)
    {
      husk_that_thing($value,$temp);
    }
  }
}
husk_that_thing($thing,$temp);
echo implode(',',$temp);//output
```

Comment: thank you. all is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try implode()?
[See this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-array-to-string-in-php/)

Comment: yes. implode not working for multi tree arrays

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in function in PHP that does this.